# name 'KMeans' is not defined in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science, k-means

[image]

I am unable to run KMeans() in my Jupyter Notebook. The same piece of code works correctly if I just use it in a Python script. I have already installed KMeans/Sklearn using.

```
!pip3 install KMeans
```

Then what's the issue?

Comment: Please don't share code/data as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above two cells are not yet executed.

Please re-run all the cells. Probably you've restarted the kernel and forgot to run the cells where you've imported the KMeans from sklearn.cluster.

Answer (score 3):

**Straightforward answer:** 
Write in a cell of the Jupyter notebook (in In[6] for example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMean
km=KMean(1)
```

And see if there is an error.

**Long answer**
You have different cells in the Jupyter notebook. You need to execute all the cells if you have restarted Jupyter Notebook.

**On your screenshots:**
It is written *In[]* in the two first pieces of code, and *In[6]* in the piece of code where you got the error.
That might mean that you did not execute the two first cells (In[]) before the third (In[6]), thus the Kmean had not been imported.

**What you can do:**
- Ensure you have executed the two first pieces of code ?
- Ensure you did not clear the variables before executing *In[6]*? (not sure if this function exists on Jupyter)

Comment: I'm new to Jupyter Notebooks and can't really understand what you're trying to say. Before In[6], I only used cells to install packages and then erased those lines. There was no other code.

Comment: I also tried to insert a cell before In[6] and reinstall KMeans but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear. You can have a look at @Strange answer as well: We're saying the same thing

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind cells in Jupyter is that you split the code in cell and when you change some part of your code you don't need to re-run all your code only parts of it.

i.e. you don't need to run the read input part of your code every time you change something.

What you did was to run the third cell first, so the import cell was not executed at all where you import `KMeans` from the `sklearn` module.

You should run the cells in order and if by any chance you get the an error regarding the KMeans class maybe you have not installed the `sklearn` module.

In order to install it, run `pip install sklearn`.

[sklearn installation notes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).